# multiple entry points using Vite3

Tags: vuejs3, vite, hybrid-mobile-app

```
I am new to vite, to start with, I don't actually know what kind of structure I need.

I need to build multiple apps but some of them depend on the same components.

is there any example is available 

multiple entry points using Vite3 & run project, build project separately 

i am having mobile & web diffrent but need to run on single project

When evere i run main need to run main only and build only same for other 

how can do this 




    enter code here


import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        appMain: fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/main/index.html', import.meta.url)),
        appOther: fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources/other/index.html', import.meta.url)),
      },
    },

    brotliSize: false,
  },
})
```

**Vite js config but not able to understand how to run project differently **

I am new to vite, to start with, I don't actually know what kind of structure I need.

```
I need to build multiple apps but some of them depend on the same components.
```

Comment: Please add the code as text/codeblock instead of an image.